# Poynting's theorem and macroscopic fields and currents

Tags: electromagnetism

One crucial thing in the derivation of the Poynting's theorem is to interpret the term $$\int \vec{E}\cdot\vec{J}d^3x$$ as the rate of change of mechanical energy of the charges. However, here the $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{J}$ are the macroscopic spatial averages of the corresponding microscopic field and current $\vec{e}$ and $\vec{j}$. I have no problem in understanding that $$\int \vec{e}\cdot\vec{j}d^3x$$ as the rate of change of mechanical energy of the charges.

However since the average of product does not equal to the product of averages in general. So I don't understand why the two volume integrals are the same. In other words, why $$\int\vec{E}\cdot\vec{J}d^3x$$ equals the rate of change of the mechanical energy of the charges.